# Drop by multiple columns groups if specific values not exit in another column in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can I drop the whole group by `city` and `district` if `date`'s value of `2018/11/1` not exits in the following dataframe:

```
  city district       date  value
0    a        c   2018/9/1     12
1    a        c  2018/10/1      4
2    a        c  2018/11/1      5
3    b        d   2018/9/1      3
4    b        d  2018/10/1      7
```

The expected result will like this:

```
  city district       date  value
0    a        c   2018/9/1     12
1    a        c  2018/10/1      4
2    a        c  2018/11/1      5
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create helper column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), compare by datetime and test if at least one true per groups with [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) and [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for possible filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = (df.assign(new=df['date'].eq('2018/11/1'))
          .groupby(['city','district'])['new'].transform('any'))
df = df[mask]
print (df)
  city district       date  value
0    a        c   2018/9/1     12
1    a        c  2018/10/1      4
2    a        c  2018/11/1      5
```

If error with misisng values in mask one possivle idea is replace misisng values in columns used for groups:

```
mask = (df.assign(new=df['date'].eq('2018/11/1'),
                  city= df['city'].fillna(-1),
                  district= df['district'].fillna(-1))
          .groupby(['city','district'])['new'].transform('any'))
df = df[mask]
print (df)
  city district       date  value
0    a        c   2018/9/1     12
1    a        c  2018/10/1      4
2    a        c  2018/11/1      5
```

Another idea is add possible misisng index values by `reindex` and also replace missing values to `False`:

```
mask = (df.assign(new=df['date'].eq('2018/11/1'))
          .groupby(['city','district'])['new'].transform('any'))
df = df[mask.reindex(df.index, fill_value=False).fillna(False)]
print (df)
  city district       date  value
0    a        c   2018/9/1     12
1    a        c  2018/10/1      4
2    a        c  2018/11/1      5
```

Comment: It generates `ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values` with my real data :(

Comment: @ahbon - I guess some misisng values in `city` or `district`, give me  asec.

Answer (score 1):

There's a special GroupBy.filter() method for this. Assuming *date* is already datetime:

```
filter_date = pd.Timestamp('2018-11-01').date()
df = df.groupby(['city', 'district']).filter(lambda x: (x['date'].dt.date == filter_date).any())
```